# How can I use loop(WHILE statement) for "WITH" clause result(tsql)?

Tags: t-sql

In my T-SQL code, I use `WITH` for reading data from a table. After reading, I want use `WHILE` to get items (first item, second item, ...) from `WITH` results and delete items from it.

Please see my code :

```
With Rep(SubjectId) As
(
    SELECT [SubjectID] FROM [BookSubjects]
        WHERE [BookID] = @BookID
)   
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT [SubjectID] FROM Rep)
BEGIN
        SELECT @SubjectID = SubjectID FROM Rep          
        SELECT @Result = @Result + CAST(@SubjectID AS varchar(10))
        DELETE FROM Rep WHERE SubjectID = @SubjectID
END
```

I guess I can't delete items result from `WITH`! But my other question is how can I set a `identity(1,1)` column to `WITH` parameters ?

In declare temp table, I use this :

```
 @ID Int Identity(1,1)
```

How can I define identity for `WITH` parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for somthing like this
:

```
create table BookSubjects(SubjectID int,BookID int)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(1,10)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(2,20)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(3,30)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(4,40)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(5,50)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(6,60)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(2,10)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(2,10)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(3,10)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(4,10)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(5,10)
insert into BookSubjects(SubjectID ,BookID ) values(6,10)

select * from BookSubjects



       ;With Rep As
        (
            SELECT [SubjectID],[BookID] FROM [BookSubjects]
            WHERE [BookID] = 10
        )
        , Rep1 As
        (
        select
        [BookID],
        stuff((
            select ',' + cast(t.[SubjectID]  as varchar(100))
            from Rep t
            where Rep.[BookID]  = t.[BookID] 
            order by t.[SubjectID] 
            for xml path('')
        ),1,1,'') as name_csv
        from Rep
        group by [BookID]

        )  
        select * from rep1
```

i use another With clause after first With an in the second With( Named Rep1)
I  convert rows return  two comma seperated colomn.
you can  change to your need.

Answer (score 1):

Common Table Expressions (`WITH` ...) can only precede single `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `MERGE` statements. However, your code seems to be very complicated for what it does.

This should do the same as your code, but it is much much more efficient:

```
DECLARE @delSubjects TABLE (
  id int NOT NULL
);
DELETE BookSubjects
  OUTPUT DELETED.SubjectID INTO @delSubjects 
  WHERE BookID=@BookID;
SET @result = (
  SELECT id+' ' 
  FROM @delSubjects 
  FOR XML PATH('')
);
```

([Link to Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51ec5/2/0))